# How do I solve this error in my application when I put it on my server?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-2.0

When I deploy my ASP.NET application to my server I get this error:
`add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"`

I have installed IIS and AJAX but this error occurs anyway.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks to all, I solve my problem temporarily,I add System.Web.extension.dll in my project bin folder then it will work properly, If you have idea behind that then share it, please.....

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the correct versions of .Net installed on the server.

Your app appears to be targetting the .Net 1.1 version of the System.Web.Extensions dll.  Is this version of the framework installed on your server?

Answer (score 0):

Is the System.Web.Extensions.dll in the same place on the server as it was on the client machine? Try copying it to the solution bin directory on the server.